# Changes to an EM-wave that is propagating in an inflating space

Tags: cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, cosmological-inflation, intensity

I am trying to get an easier picture of what happens to an em-wave considering space expansion. My question is: If a star in a non-inflating space emits light recorded at a certain distance of the same wavelength and intensity, will in an inflating space that expands twice in a certain time from the emission to the arrival of the signal from the star (or source), the receiver move twice as far and the recorded light will double its wavelength and have 4 times less intensity (due to larger sphere area)?
[image]

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: This question seems to be more about space expansion in general than cosmological inflation. If this is so, please replace the cosmological-expansion tag with the space-expansion one. The title and body may need some rewording also.